# $\sum_{1\leq l \lt m\lt n} \dfrac{1}{5^l3^m2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

I need a help to deal with the serie $\sum_{1\leq l \lt m\lt n} \dfrac{1}{5^l3^m2^n}$ (OBM level university, 2018).
Some ideia?
Thanks very much.

Comment: I'm ashamed because of the duplicate question. I confess that I've tried research when was posting, but for some reason I didn't get the first question. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{1\le l< m<n}^{K}{\frac{1}{5^l 3^m 2^n}} &=& \sum_{l=1}^{K} {\frac{1}{5^{l}}  \sum_{m=l+1}^{K} {\frac{1}{3^{m} }\sum_{n=m+1}^{K} {\frac{1}{2^{n}}} } }  \\
&=& \sum_{l=1}^{K} {\frac{1}{5^{l}}  \sum_{m=l+1}^{K} {\frac{1}{3^{m}}  {\frac{2^{K}-2^{m}}{2^{m+K}}   }  } }  \\
 &=& \sum_{l=1}^{K} {\frac{1}{5^{l}} \frac{1}{5} \left( \frac{3^{1-K}}{2^{1+K}}-\frac{3+2}{3^{l} 2^{1+K}} +\frac{1}{6^l} \right) }\\
 &=& \frac{1}{203} \frac{1}{2^{3+K} 3^{K} 5^{1+K}}    \left(7 \times 2^{3+K} (5\times 3)^{K} -58 \times 3^{K} 5^{k+1} +609\times 5^{K}-375\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

For $K\to \infty$, this becomes $\frac{1}{145}$.

Comment: Given the fact that this has been flagged as an exact duplicate of an answered question 20mn before you posted your answer, *why* did you still write it?

Comment: My apologies. Didn't notice that. Do you want me to delete it?

Comment: Wasted my time! Should have waited:-)

Comment: No, don't delete it. It's just possibly a waste of your time indeed, if down the road the automatic system deletes the question. (This may happen. I still haven't figured out how this automatic deletion works.)

Comment: @NivPai, I've done the calculus by myself with all the ideias in this topic and finally arrived to the correct result $\dfrac{1}{145}$, so I thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$\sum_{1\le l<m<n}=\sum_{l=1}^\infty\sum_{m=l+1}^\infty\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty$$
Each sum is a geometric series.

Comment: thanks, I didn't note this before...!

Answer (score 2):

More generally,
if $0 < a, b ,c < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
s(a, b, c)
&=\sum_{1\leq l \lt m\lt n} a^lb^mc^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sum_{l=1}^{m-1}a^lb^mc^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}b^mc^n\sum_{l=1}^{m-1}a^l\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}b^m\dfrac{a-a^m}{1-a}\\
&=\dfrac1{1-a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}b^m(a-a^m)\\
&=\dfrac1{1-a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n\left(a\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}b^m-\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}(ab)^m\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{1-a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n\left(a\dfrac{b-b^{n}}{1-b}-\dfrac{(ab)-(ab)^{n}}{1-ab}\right)\\
&=\left(\dfrac1{1-a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^na\dfrac{b-b^{n}}{1-b}-\dfrac1{1-a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n\dfrac{(ab)-(ab)^{n}}{1-ab}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{(1-a)(1-b)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^na(b-b^{n})\\
&\quad -\dfrac1{(1-a)(1-ab)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n((ab)-(ab)^{n})\\
&=\dfrac1{(1-a)(1-b)}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^nab-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^na(b)^{n}\right)\\
&\quad -\dfrac1{(1-a)(1-ab)}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^nab-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n(ab)^{n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{(1-a)(1-b)}\left(ab\dfrac{c}{1-c}-\dfrac{abc}{1-bc}\right)\\
&\quad -\dfrac1{(1-a)(1-ab)}\left(ab\dfrac{c}{1-c}-\dfrac{abc}{1-abc}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{abc}{(1-a)(1-b)}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-c}-\dfrac{1}{1-bc}\right)\\
&\quad -\dfrac{abc}{(1-a)(1-ab)}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-c}-\dfrac{1}{1-abc}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{abc}{(1-a)(1-b)}\left(\dfrac{c-bc}{(1-c)(1-bc)}\right)\\
&\quad -\dfrac{abc}{(1-a)(1-ab)}\left(\dfrac{c-abc}{(1-c)(1-abc)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{abc}{(1-a)(1-b)}\left(\dfrac{c(1-b)}{(1-c)(1-bc)}\right)\\
&\quad -\dfrac{abc}{(1-a)(1-ab)}\left(\dfrac{c(1-ab)}{(1-c)(1-abc)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{abc^2}{(1-a)(1-c)(1-bc)}\\
&\quad -\dfrac{abc^2}{(1-a)(1-c)(1-abc)}\\
&=\dfrac{abc^2}{(1-a)(1-c)(1-bc)((1-abc)}((1-abc)-(1-bc))\\
&=\dfrac{abc^2}{(1-a)(1-c)(1-bc)((1-abc)}(bc-abc)\\
&=\dfrac{abc^2}{(1-a)(1-c)(1-bc)((1-abc)}bc(1-a)\\
&=\dfrac{ab^2c^3}{(1-c)(1-bc)(1-abc)}\\
\end{array}
$

If $a=1/5,
b=1/3,
c=1/2$,
this is
$\dfrac{1/(5\ 3^2 2^3)}{(1/2)(5/6)(29/30)}
=\dfrac{1}{5\ 3^2 2^3(1/2)(5/6)(29/30)}
=\dfrac{1}{ 5\ 29}
=\dfrac{1}{145}
$
which agrees with
NivPal's answer.

Comment: interesting! Thanks for the rich comment

Comment: And I generalized it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891305/evaluating-sum-i-1-1-infty-sum-i-2-1i-1-1-sum-i-3-1i-2-1

Comment: I'll study there too, thanks very much. I'm reading again you comment and I have a doubt. On the passage to the second line, why didn't you take $=\sum_{n=\boxed{3}}^{\infty}\sum_{m=\boxed{2}}^{n-1}\sum_{l=1}^{m-1}a^lb^mc^n$? Or this doesn't make any difference? I confess that I feel I'm yet confused with sums blending, so I hope you could help me again.