# Evaluating $\sum_{i_1=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1-1} \sum_{i_3=1}^{i_2-1} ... \sum_{i_m=1}^{i_{m-1}-1} \prod_{k=1}^m a_k^{i_k}$

Tags: summation, geometric-series

This is
a generalization
of my answer to
[$\sum_{1\leq l \lt m\lt n} \dfrac{1}{5^l3^m2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890450/sum-1-leq-l-lt-m-lt-n-dfrac15l3m2n)

I showed there that,
if $0 < a, b ,c < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
s(a, b, c)
&=\sum_{1\leq l \lt m\lt n} a^lb^mc^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sum_{l=1}^{m-1}a^lb^mc^n\\
&=\dfrac{ab^2c^3}{(1-c)(1-bc)(1-abc)}\\
\end{array}
$

Obviously

$\begin{array}\\
s(c)
&=\sum_{1\leq n} c^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n\\
&=\dfrac{c}{1-c}\\
\end{array}
$

and,
with a little more work,

$\begin{array}\\
s(b, c)
&=\sum_{1\leq m\lt n} b^mc^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}b^mc^n\\
&=\dfrac{bc^2}{(1-c)(1-bc)}\\
\end{array}
$

This led to
the following conjecture:

If
$A_m 
= (a_1, ..., a_m)
=(a_i)_{i=1}^m
$
and
$s(A_m)
=\sum_{i_1=1}^{\infty}
\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1-1}
\sum_{i_3=1}^{i_2-1}
...
\sum_{i_m=1}^{i_{m-1}-1}
\prod_{k=1}^m a_k^{i_k}
$
then
$s(A_m)
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^m a_k^{m+1-k}}{\prod_{k=1}^m (1-\prod_{j=1}^ka_j)}
$.

I have a proof,
but it is really cumbersome
(as is just the
statement of the problem
and the result).

My hope is that
someone can
come up with a better
statement of the sum
and proof of the result.

Comment: I have noticed this was second time you have created ([tag:generalization]) tag. (And in the past this tag was created by other users and removed each time.) I think that probably it would be better to discuss the tag on meta first, since it is unclear whether or not this tag can be useful. (Relevant discussion on meta: [Should every new tag be discussed on meta before creation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17023)) After you see this comment, feel free to ping me here or [in tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2018/8/23) - then I can remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slightly different approach to evaluate $s(A_m)$ by using a relabelling of the indices. I illustrate it for the case $s(b,c)$, but it relatively easy to generalise.
$$
s(b,c) = \sum_{1 \leq m<n} b^m c^n
$$
If we introduce $\delta = n - m \geq 1$, we can rewrite the sum as
$$
s(b,c) = \sum_{1\leq m} \sum_{1 \leq \delta} b^m c^{m+\delta} = \sum_{1 \leq m} (b c
)^m \sum_{1\leq \delta} c^\delta = \frac{b c}{1 - b c} \frac{c}{1-c}
$$
where I made the summation run over $\delta$. This of course gives the same final result that you already found.

You can use this approach to introduce differences between the summation indices $i_k$ and the final results becomes product of independent summations over unbounded positive indices and result in the expected product.

The only thing that remains to do, is to use induction to prove the final result, but I am sure you can do this yourself.

Comment: That's a much simpler way. I'll accept.